# Is it possible to register a domain with a '.sea' extension?

Tags: domain-registration, top-level-domains

I want to register a domain with the `.sea` extension, is that possible now that a lot of new extensions are being released?

Comment: You can view a list of top-level domains that have been approved [here](https://www.icann.org/resources/pages/tlds-2012-02-25-en) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Internet_top-level_domains). That extension isn't listed, so it's not possible.

Answer (score 6):

The [authoritative list of all TLDs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14444138/1591669) is [**http://www.iana.org/domains/root/db**](http://www.iana.org/domains/root/db).

The top-level domain `.sea` is not listed.

---

It may of course be possible to register it with [alternative DNS roots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternative_DNS_root), but that’s probably not what you want, because your visitors would have to configure the list of their DNS servers accordingly.

cesidianroot.net [lists `.sea`](http://cesidianroot.net/alt-tlds-update.html) as belonging to the [Principality of Sealand](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principality_of_Sealand). I couldn’t find any registration information, so I guess this TLD is not open to the public.

Comment: Haha Principality of Sealand. Remember hearing an episode about it on This American Life or something.